# Excel for Mac- Converting tested windows Excel macro to Mac

Tags: excel, macos

I am a newbie to macros but I was able to find and modify a macro to works for what I needed. The macro is for a Form that once filled out the user will push the "Save and email" button and the following will happen:

1. save location window will open, the file will be converted and saved as .pdf (the file name is predetermined based on cells information)
2. the active sheet will be converted to .pdf it will be attached to an email.
   I was very proud of my achievement until I tested it on my Mac and realized that it will not work. Now, I am faced with a challenge of converting the macro from Windows to Mac in order for the keep the functionality of the Form.

Below is the tested code on a Windows Excel:

```
Sub Button9_Click()


Dim xSht          As Worksheet
Dim xFileDlg      As FileDialog
Dim xFolder       As String
Dim xYesorNo      As Integer
Dim xOutlookObj   As Object, signature As String
Dim xEmailObj     As Object
Dim xUsedRng      As Range
 
Set xSht = ActiveSheet
Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
 
If xFileDlg.Show = True Then
   xFolder = xFileDlg.SelectedItems(1)
Else
   MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must Specify Destination Folder"
   Exit Sub
End If
xFolder = xFolder + "\" + xSht.Range("G3").Text + ".pdf"
 
'Check if file already exist
If Len(Dir(xFolder)) > 0 Then
    xYesorNo = MsgBox(xFolder & " already exists." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to overwrite it?", _
                      vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")
    On Error Resume Next
    If xYesorNo = vbYes Then
        Kill xFolder
    Else
        MsgBox "if you don't overwrite the existing PDF, I can't continue." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Exiting Macro"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Unable to delete existing file.  Please make sure the file is not open or write protected." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Unable to Delete File"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
 
Set xUsedRng = xSht.UsedRange
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(xUsedRng.Cells) <> 0 Then
    'Save as PDF file
    xSht.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=xFolder, Quality:=xlQualityStandard
     
    'Create Outlook email
    Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
    With xEmailObj
        .Display
        .Subject = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FORM").Range("G3")
        .To = "name"
        .CC = " "
        .body = "Hi ..," & vbLf & vbLf _
          & "The Parts Request Form is attached in PDF format." & vbLf & vbLf _
          & "Regards," & vbLf & vbLf _
          & Application.UserName & vbLf & vbLf _
          & "..." & vbLf _
          & "..., ..." & vbLf _
          & "..." & vbLf _

        
        .Attachments.Add xFolder
        If DisplayEmail = False Then
            '.Send
        End If
    End With
Else
  MsgBox "The active worksheet cannot be blank"
  Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner, I appreciate your fast reply to my question. However, I am confused as to what the fix was? I believe that I pasted the macro wrong in my initial post because it has exactly the same structure as the one you corrected. My request for help was related to the conversion of the Macro from Win to MacOS or having a macro working in both versions of Excel. The macro is fully functional in Win Excel environment. I do appreciate your feedback.

Comment: I did not answer.  I simply edited the post to make it more readable.